# different types of initialization in C++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++, and am rather confused as to the different types of initialization.

You can do:

```
T a;
```

which, as far as I can tell, will sometimes initialize `a` and sometimes won't, depending on if `T` has a default constructor.

You can also do:

```
T a(); // or
T a(1, 2, 3... args);
```

; (in some cases):

```
T a = 1; // implicitly converted to T sometimes?
```

; if there is no constructor:

```
T a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

; and also:

```
T a = T(1, 2, 3);
```

.

If you want to allocate on the heap, there's

```
T a = new T(1, 2, 3);
```

Is there anything else?

I'd like to know if a) I've got all the types of initialization covered and b) when to use each type?

Comment: No, `T a()` is not what you think it is.

Comment: And `T a = new T(1, 2, 3);` is not valid (unless `T` was, say, a class type with a converting constructor taking a `T*`).

Comment: could you guys elaborate/answer with the right things? Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your questions, I think you should stop learning C++ and start with really important basics before with C programming.

Comment: @Julio: Please don't encourage people to learn C in order to learn C++. We _don't need_ more "C with classes" people in the world.

Comment: I am not saying that one should know C prior to learn C++, I'm saying that C is a good way to learn memory management basics since it does not offers as many ways as C++ to add things on stack or heap. I think it must be very hard to imagine what a C++ program does for someone without any "low-level" background. So I should have said: have a look at how memory works and is managed. This is only regarding "T a = new T(1, 2, 3);".

Comment: @JulioGuerra: You don't need to know about atoms and molecules and aerodynamic theory before you can learn how to throw a ball. That all comes later, if and when needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You made a few mistakes. I'll clear them up.

```
// Bog-standard declaration.
// Initialisation rules are a bit complex.
T a;


// WRONG - this declares a function.
T a();

// Bog-standard declaration, with constructor arguments.
// (*)
T a(1, 2, 3... args);

// Bog-standard declaration, with *one* constructor argument
// (and only if there's a matching, _non-explicit_ constructor).
// (**)
T a = 1;

// Uses aggregate initialisation, inherited from C.
// Not always possible; depends on layout of T.
T a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

// Invoking C++0x initializer-list constructor.
T a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

// This is actually two things.
// First you create a [nameless] rvalue with three
// constructor arguments (*), then you copy-construct
// a [named] T from it (**).
T a = T(1, 2, 3);

// Heap allocation, the result of which gets stored
// in a pointer.
T* a = new T(1, 2, 3);

// Heap allocation without constructor arguments.
T* a = new T;
```

Comment: You can also do `T a(b);` which is the same as `T a = b;` where `b` is also a `T`.

Comment: I just edited my comment, see if you still think so, I think the edit makes a difference. Also +1 for thorough answer.

Comment: @Seth: Same thing as the third non-comment line, really, just with a `T` rather than an `int` as its constructor argument. Doesn't really make a difference to the discussion here, methinks.

Comment: yeah, I guess it's just what you want to call a copy constructor and what you don't, because `T a(other T)` will call a so-called copy constructor and `T a(1)` doesn't unless `T` is `int`. But it's just a name-game, so whatever.

Comment: Thanks! It's so hard to remember things about declarations and *s coming from Java.

Answer (score 2):

> T a = 1; // implicitly converted to T sometimes?

You can do that if T has a copy constructor.

> T a();

this sound more like a function declaration of "a" that return a type T

Comment: (a) It's not a copy constructor unless `1` is a `T` (which it is not). (b) Please prefer "function declaration" to "method prototype", which is not well-defined terminology in C++.

Comment: @Mac: How can `1`, `2` or `3` ever be types?

Comment: @Mac `T a(1, 2, 3 .. args);` will never be a prototype because of the literals `1, 2, 3`. Or, simply the lack of types preceding them, if they weren't literals.

Comment: @Tomalak, @Seth: true. Blame it on not enough sleep :) comment removed

Comment: @TomalakGeretkal: @Overdose is correct. copy initialization _requires_ a copy constructor even if the initializer is not the same type, though.

Comment: @Charles: That's where I stop calling it a copy constructor. A copy constructor for a `T` takes a `ref-to-const-T`. A constructor taking `int` is just an arbitrary constructor ... to my mind at least.

Comment: @0verbose: `T a = 1` is OK only if `T` has a non-`explicit` constructor that can accept the integer as an argument. Whether you call that a "copy constructor" or not appears to be open to debate. I would not, which is what my original comment was saying.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: thanks..i put it again in my answer.. and I'm not something like overdose... :) It's 0verbose (zero verbose, or overbose depend on how you want to read!)

Comment: @TomalakGeretkal: My only disagreement with your definition of copy-constructor is that it can take a reference with any cv-qualifier, I'm not sure why you thought I was disagreeing on this point. All I was saying is that @0verbose was correct to point out that copy-initialization [for objects of class type] requires a copy-constructor. What copy initialization means is convert the initializer to the destination type and _copy_ the result of that conversion to the destination. `T a = 1;` requires that there is an implicit conversion from `1` to type `T` and that `T` is copy constructable.

Comment: @Charles: And I didn't disagree with that. But adding that extra conversion step is quite not what any of us were talking about, I think.

Comment: @TomalakGeretkal: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "extra conversion step". Whatever you meant, there was obviously some confusion caused by your original comment because @0verbose originally wrote that `T a = 1;` requires a copy construct which is 99.9% correct in my book and after your comment he "fixed" his answer by removing this correct assertion.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: It was not a "correct assertion". The standard tells us what a copy constructor is, and a constructor for `T` that takes an `int` is not one of them.