# C++ calling the default constructor with parens vs without parens

Tags: c++, default-constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [different types of initialization in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845534/different-types-of-initialization-in-c)

Is there any difference at all between calling the base constructor like

```
Foo afoo;
```

vs

```
Foo afoo();
```

Comment: Yes, #2 is declaring a function.

Comment: Yes, the first constructs an object of type `Foo`, the second doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: the first is a variable definition, the second is a function declaration. Now lets discuss the more interesting question of the difference between these two expressions:

```
new Foo()
new Foo
```

Whether there is a difference depends on the type of `Foo` and its members!

- if `Foo` has an explicit default constructor the two are identical
- if there is no default constructor, there is potentially a difference! If there is any member which is an aggregate or a built-in type, it will be initialized in the first expresion but not in the second except all members which have default construct will be default constructed.

Note that this also applies to members of classes. For variables you cannot use the form using parenthesis, i.e. to make sure the object is initialized you need to use

```
Foo aFoo = Foo();
```

If there is no explicit constructor taking an argument or you don't know (e.g. in template code).

Comment: thanks for the breakdown and sorry for the repeat '?'